# How to query a region in a fasta file using biopython?

Tags: biopython, fasta

I have a fasta file with some reference genome.
I would like to obtain the reference nucleotides as a string given the chromosome, start and end indexes.

I am looking for a function which would look like this in code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
p = '/path/to/refernce.fa'
seqs = SeqIO.parse(p.open(), 'fasta')
string = seqs.query(id='chr7', start=10042, end=10252)
```

and string should be like : 'GGCTACGAACT...'

All I have found is how to iterate over seqs, and how to pull data from NCBI, which is not what I'm looking for.
What is the right way to do this in biopython?

Comment: does this work with biopython `next(r for r in seqs if r.id == "chr7").seq[10042:10252]`? note it might be end+1

Comment: It might, but it would take a while, and the solution below was perfectly good :)
Thanks a lot for your reply thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, [biopython](https://biopython.org/) does not currently have this functionality. For random lookups using an index (please see [samtools faidx](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-faidx.html)), you'll probably want either [pysam](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) or [pyfaidx](https://pythonhosted.org/pyfaidx/). Here's an example using the [pysam.FastaFile](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pysam.FastaFile) class which allows you to quickly 'fetch' sequences in a region:

```
import pysam
ref = pysam.FastaFile('/path/to/reference.fa')
seq = ref.fetch('chr7', 10042, 10252)
print(seq)
```

Or using [pyfaidx](https://pythonhosted.org/pyfaidx/) and the 'get_seq' method:

```
from pyfaidx import Fasta
ref = Fasta('/path/to/reference.fa')
seq = ref.get_seq('chr7', 10042, 10252)
print(seq)
```

Comment: While biopython dosen't provide a function exactly for this, it should be easy to extract the relevant information from the biopython `SeqRecord`